# success in logcat but empty screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have this one problem. and because of this, i cant do any other because i have to refer to this page. I would be grateful if anyone could point out the mistake i made.

I wanted to view the details of a specific product where the button from previous page (list) will pass the ID parameter to the page (details). there is no error in the Java code or PHP code. i'm sure about this because the Logcat shows the results accordingly (as i added the log thing everywhere). but the page is empty in the emulator. i don't understand why this happens as the layout is designed same as other pages as well. In case you need the code, its as below:

Java code:
list.java

```
ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    details.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

Java code: details.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_details);


        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        Log.d("pid is:",pid);

        new GetProductDetails().execute();

    }

 class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Details.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    int success;
                    try {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_details, "GET", params);


   Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());


                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BOOK); 
        int i = productObj.length();    //line 1

JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(i);

String title = "Title : "+ product.getString(TAG_TITLE);
    String description = product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);


HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);                              

eventsList.add(map);

Log.d("Title", title);
Log.d("Description", description);
            }   
}
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            Details.this, eventsList,
R.layout.list_item2, new String[] { TAG_PID, TAG_TITLE, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
    new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.title, R.id.description });                  
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Layout: details.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

```
04-15 00:05:28.005: D/All Products:(4345): {"success":1,"books":[{"author":"Agnesh","category":"Fiction","title":"The Immortals of Shiva","pid":"1","price":"150","description":"Life of Shiva","discount":"20%"},{"author":"Chetan Bhagat","category":"Drama","title":"3 Mistakes of My Life","pid":"14","price":"180","description":"Story of a 3 friends and their destiny","discount":"30%"},{"author":"Chetan Bhagat","category":"Comedy","title":"Two States","pid":"15","price":"175","description":"Love Story","discount":"5%"},{"author":"Charles Darwin","category":"Personality Developm","title":"How to win friends","pid":"16","price":"250","description":"Building your confidence","discount":"10%"},{"author":"Paulo Coelho","category":"Science Fiction","title":"Alchemist","pid":"17","price":"300","description":"In search of Gold","discount":"20%"},{"author":"Vivekananda","category":"Social Awareness","title":"Call to the Nation","pid":"18","price":"100","description":"Knowing yourself","discount":"5%"}]}
04-15 00:05:29.675: D/pid is:(4345): 18
04-15 00:05:30.995: D/Single Product Details(4345): {"book":[{"author":"Vivekananda","category":"Social Awareness","title":"Call to the Nation","pid":"18","price":"100","description":"Knowing yourself","discount":"5%"}],"success":1}
04-15 00:05:31.000: W/System.err(4345): org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)
04-15 00:05:31.005: W/System.err(4345):     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
04-15 00:05:31.005: W/System.err(4345):     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:480)
04-15 00:05:31.005: W/System.err(4345):     at com.spyraa.store.Details$GetProductDetails$1.run(Details.java:104)
04-15 00:05:31.005: W/System.err(4345):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-15 00:05:31.005: W/System.err(4345):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 00:05:31.005: W/System.err(4345):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-15 00:05:31.010: W/System.err(4345):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-15 00:05:31.010: W/System.err(4345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 00:05:31.010: W/System.err(4345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-15 00:05:31.010: W/System.err(4345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-15 00:05:31.010: W/System.err(4345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-15 00:05:31.015: W/System.err(4345):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 00:05:31.020: D/AndroidRuntime(4345): Shutting down VM
04-15 00:05:31.020: W/dalvikvm(4345): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:485)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at com.spyraa.store.Details$GetProductDetails$2.run(Details.java:166)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3743)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at com.spyraa.store.Details$GetProductDetails.onPostExecute(Details.java:156)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at com.spyraa.store.Details$GetProductDetails.onPostExecute(Details.java:1)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-15 00:05:31.030: E/AndroidRuntime(4345):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

new logcat:

```
04-15 01:37:50.695: D/pid is:(8773): 18
04-15 01:37:52.285: D/Single Product Details(8773): {"book":[{"author":"Vivekananda","category":"Social Awareness","title":"Call to the Nation","pid":"18","price":"100","description":"Knowing yourself","discount":"5%"}],"success":1}
04-15 01:37:52.295: D/AndroidRuntime(8773): Shutting down VM
04-15 01:37:52.295: W/dalvikvm(8773): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at com.spyraa.bookstore.BookDetails$GetProductDetails$1.run(BookDetails.java:127)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-15 01:37:52.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 01:38:00.015: I/Process(8773): Sending signal. PID: 8773 SIG: 9
```

thank you so much!

Comment: Could you post the output from LogCat?

Comment: @thomas88wp, yup, updated.

Comment: Are you using a list adapter?

Comment: We're missing part of your AsyncTask.. what does it do with the JSON values once they're retrieved? And I don't see the log statement where you're getting most of that output.

Comment: @Paradopolis, ya for the list.java page.

Comment: @thomas88wp, i get what you mean with the AsyncTask. but I don't get you about the log statement. what you mean?

Comment: What is your `BookDetails.java` at line 127 ?

Comment: @swayam, this line. (eventsList.add(map);)

Comment: I think your problem is solved by now. So, yeah..good luck ahead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is missing some code so some of this answer is a shot in the dark, but the crucial steps you should have here are:

- You've inflated your xml file, both for your activity and your adapter (I am assuming a custom adapter is being used)
- You've picked up your list view from your view with it's ID
- You've set the listview's adapter
- You've set it's onClick listener (I can see that you've done that.)
- You've overrided the adapter's getView to set your data properly

If you've done those 5 things, then what are you doing with the JSON Data once you get it? You should be telling the activity to handle the data, which should also be done in a handler since you are doing this with async tasks.

Also make sure you are adding the data to the adapter in some way.

Finally, here's a good tutorial on listViews with custom list adapters that might have some code that helps you spot the error (it doesn't look like it's in any of the code we can see) http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: I updated the code as according to your comment and the logcat looks like the updated logcat. I know there is mistake in the details page where i commented //line 1. Is it Possible for you to make it right?

Comment: You are getting an array, the array has length i, then you try to get an object at location i. If i have an array of size 1, the only object is at 0. Try getting an object at i-1. That should solve your ArrayOutOfRange exception EDIT: To further specify, it's the line JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(i); make that line i-1

Comment: Is it the same error? I thought that would atleast get rid of the ArrayIndex error...

Comment: The error is now in your bookdetails when you try and get the product details. The code for bookdetails is not here, but this is just another null pointer issue.

Comment: ya my mistake, sorry. i imported the wrong PHP file. i changed and run it again. i have updated the new logcat. if you see, it shows the PID and the book details now. but still there are errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28202/discussion-between-paradopolis-and-a-k-c-f-l)